# RCTPushNotificationManager - Command Analyze failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

I'm trying to start my react native app but builds failed. Push notification is already working in the app and running on other system.
Trying to run the app on following environment:

- MacBook Pro: Intel i5
- Node: 16.6
- Xcode: 14.2
- React: 16.8
- React Native: 59.9

I keep getting this error:

> Command Analyze failed with a nonzero exit code.